# "avoir à faire qch" vs. "devoir faire qqch" ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

I had never seen the construct "avoir à faire qch" until just now, not in 6 years of studying French. I didn't think the English expression "to have to do something" had a literal French equivalent. Normally I always see the use of *devoir* instead.

Is this expression common? Does it mean the same thing? What is the difference, if any, between these two phrases?

> Je dois partir.
>   J'ai à partir.

Comment: in my experience the second is something you hear much more often in the negative: "on n'a qu'à.... il n'y à qu'à..." to mean "the only thing we have to do is..." or in a non-standard register, "y a qu'à" for the same.

Comment: True! Now that you point it out, I see that phrasing all the time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both sentences have the same meaning. However, the first one is more common.

Definition of "avoir à" :

> Devoir faire quelque chose, être dans l'obligation de : *J'ai à régler quelques détails.*

[Source : Larousse.fr](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/avoir/7141/locution?q=avoir#160130)

Answer (score 2):

> Je dois partir.

Il est de mon devoir de partir, c'est une contrainte à laquelle je dois me soumettre.

> J'ai à partir.

*J'ai* [quelque chose] *à faire* qui est une tournure correcte, entre dans le langage familier lorsque le verbe d'action est changé  --> *J'ai à partir*, s'emploie surtout à l'oral en France.

Comment: *J'ai à boire* je veux bien, mais ça a un autre sens. *J'ai à partir* je ne crois pas l'avoir jamais entendu.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good question

I'm French. (my apologies for inevitable mistakes.)
Of course some differences exist, but thinking about it, I don't succeed in finding a general rule for "devoir" or "avoir à".
Like in English with "must" and "have to."

Regarding *avoir à faire qqch*, I don't have the impression that there is any difference between that and *to have to do*.

You're right, though, it's not common. Usually, we say *avoir qqch à faire.*

Hum...I think we do this inversion often when the sentence is longer, when there are qualifications to "qqch"~

> "J'ai des choses à faire"

but:

> "J'ai à faire des choses qui/que..."
> "J'ai à faire des choses que"

In the past tense, it sounds better.

> J'ai eu à faire certaines choses que...

I think that's to avoid breaking the continuity of the sentence.

> J'ai eu à faire des/certaines recherches que mes camarades avaient négligées.

Of course, else you can say:

> J'ai eu des recherches à faire, que mes camarades avaient négligées."

Notice I used a comma.

As "hunter" said on a precedent post, we use this turn with "juste" or "ne + que":

> Tu as juste à faire ce qu'on te dit (de faire)
>
> Parfait ! Il n'a plus qu'à signer.
>
> Maintenant, on n'a plus qu'à attendre
> Maintenant, on a juste à attendre

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! You can click "edit" underneath your answer to view the "source" of your answer and see how I made some formatting changes to help you in the future. Thanks for the answer!